# integral from a to b is equal to integral from a to c + integral from c to b

Tags: calculus

I come up with a really basic calculus question.

So I know the integration rule $$\int_a^b f(x) dx=\int_a^c f(x) dx+\int_c^b f(x) dx$$

But my question is does the function $f$ have to be continuous on the interval [a,b]? Or does it work no matter what $f$ is?

Answer (score 0):

It works for every integrable function from $[a,b]$ into $\mathbb R$. And it works both with the Riemann integral and with the Lebesgue integral.

Answer (score 0):

It will work no matter if $f$ is continuous or discontinuous. It happens because of the definition of integration of $f$ from a to b.
Definite integration is defined as the sum of areas of infinitely small rectangles from one point to another.

$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx = \lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{a}^\infty \int_{a}^{\frac{i}{n}}f(x)dx
$$
This can always be broken into two part since there are infinite terms
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{a}^k \int_{a}^{\frac{i}{n}}f(x)dx + 
\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k}^\infty \int_{a}^{\frac{i}{n}}f(x)dx
$$
where $k = c.n$
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx = \int_{a}^{c} f(x)dx + \int_{c}^{b} f(x)dx 
$$
And since its just summation there is no constraint on function being continous or not.